# Allowing cloud run service with internal traffic ingress to be accessible in other projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-networking

I have an API launched on a cloud run service in **project dev**. I don't want to expose the API so I set it's *ingress* to **Allow internal and Cloud load balancing traffic**.

I have another cloud run frontend application in a **different project**. It's connected with a VPC connector to the project's VPC and routes all traffic through the VPC connector.

I want to access the same API service from the previous project so I basically created a VPC Peering between the two projects thinking that traffic to the other project's cloud run service will go through the Peering.
It seems not to be the case as my application is still not able to reach the other project's API cloud run service. The frontend service sends the traffic not directly to the cloud run url but it sends it through a server/api request (**Using Next.JS API route here for context**) so I was of the view that it will go through the VPC connector, through the Peering and find the other project's cloud run url.

Is there something I did wrong here or it's not a setup that's going to work at the moment.

Comment: VPC connectors and peering connections are not transitive which means they do not route to other networks.

Comment: I see, so is there any way around this, thus to ensure that I can keep the API private in project A but allow project B to still access it?

Comment: Use authorization (OIDC Identity Tokens) to authorize access instead of networking and routing. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/overview

Comment: @JohnHanley, but this is also a bit strange because the VPC connector basically allows you to route the cloud run requests through a subnet. And if a subnet is being broadcasted to another vpc through peering, then should that not also allow the cloud run service to be found in the other project? I checked the vpc access connectors ip address range and it's showing in the other project's imported routes.

Comment: Transitive means A->B->C. The fact that B can route to A and C, does not mean A can route to C.

Comment: @JohnHanley, ok thanks very much for the explanation. Is there anywhere in the google cloud documentation I can find this information about the peering/connectors and the transitivity? I will checkout the authorization you mentioned earlier to see.

Comment: Search for the word `transitive` on this document: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering

Comment: The network transitiveness does not seem to apply to vpc access connector. It applies to different network connections but in this case a connector is not a network.  So in this case we still have 2 networks, N1 (connector sends requests through N1 so it's part of N1 routes) and N2. So there's no transitivity here and on this page, https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/serverless-vpc-access#supported_services, it says vpc access connector supports vpc peering.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249605/discussion-between-lance-armah-abraham-and-john-hanley).

Comment: You are misunderstanding GCP networking. Cloud Run is not part of your VPC, therefore it is another network (owned by Google Cloud).  A connector routes traffic from one network to another network. Cloud Run traffic cannot be routed (transition via a connected/peered network) to a third network using Google services.

Comment: @LanceArmah-Abraham Were you able to get the answers for your questions? If so, kindly post it as an answer so other members can see it too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCP Serverless VPC access connectors and VPC Peering are not transitive by default.

Non transitivity in GCP networking basically means that if we have 3 networks, A,B and C. If network A is connected to B and B is connected to C, it does not mean that A is connected to C. Read more on GCP network peering transitivity here: [vpc-peering-docs](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/vpc-peering).

Cloud run does not live on the user or organization's VPC but lives in a separate network (owned by Google).
Hence when the network in project A is peered with the network in project B, the connection from the cloud run service becomes a third network and since peering is not transitive, the cloud run network can of course connect to resources in the same project through the serverless access vpc connector but cannot connect to the network in project B even though the two networks are peered.

If you still want to connect your cloud run services in a project to different project services privately, then consider reading this documentation: [cloud run authentication](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/overview). With this method, you can restrict traffic to require authentication using IAM credentials for example.

Credit to [John Hanley](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8016720/john-hanley)